# Attempt to removeClass in jquery fails

Tags: jquery, html, removeclass

I am attempting to remove the classes `div1` and `intro` from this HTML code.

**Snippet sample :**

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello");
    $("div").removeClass("div1");
    $("p").removeClass("intro");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
<div class="div3">div 3</div>
<div class="div4">div 4</div>
<p class="intro">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Now when I click on the div I get hello alert but div1 and intro classes are not removed. Any suggestions on what I might be missing here ?

Update:
I should have been using remove instead of removeClass.
**[Fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/)**.

Comment: The `intro` class is removed just fine in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q251jss3/1/). The `div1` class won't be removed because you're targetting `p` elements, none of which have the `div1` class.

Comment: Sorry i tried removing it. Here is the updated code

Comment: Are you trying to make the element disappear from the display? `removeClass()` doesn't do that. You just want `remove()`.

Comment: yes i was trying to make them disappear

Comment: Are you trying to make the clicked element disappear, or everything with classes div and intro?

Comment: I am trying to make div1 and intro disappear whenever i click on any of the divs unfortunately nothing happens and i only get the alert

Comment: I added an answer below which does what you expect

Comment: @mcon that works but I would like to lknow why my method is not working

Comment: [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) are different

Comment: @Hodrobond okay I think i know why the items are still there because the classes get removed but the content is still there. I guess i should be using remove here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the issue was a misunderstanding between [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/). OP wanted to remove an element from the DOM, and should therefore use `remove()`, instead of wanting to remove the class using `removeClass()`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3jtwrvh/2/)

Comment: Can you please explain your problem a little more? In the jsfiddle, both the intro class and div1 class are removed if you click a div. What are you trying to achieve? I may not be understanding your problem correctly.

Comment: It is not being removed in my window

Comment: What isn't being removed when you click what? Both of these classes will only be removed if you click one of the four `div`s. Are there any errors in your console?

Comment: When i click on the div then div1 and intro classes should be removed

Comment: I have updated the fiddle with background colors on the classes which are removed when you click a div. If the issue still persists, please open your developer tools and report and errors in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133844/discussion-between-hodrobond-and-james-franco).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove the elements from the DOM, run the script like this:

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){
    alert("Hello");
    $(".div1").remove();
    $(".intro").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
<div class="div3">div 3</div>
<div class="div4">div 4</div>
<p class="intro">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This is another paragraph.</p>
```

`removeClass('intro1')` will remove the `intro` class property from the object. `remove()` is the function that will remove it from the DOM itself.

Comment: yes that works but my question is why my code is not working ? Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: thanks for assisting with the remove function in jquery that helped. Seems like i was using removeClass which is wrong and should be using remove

Answer (score -1):

You're selecting `p` element and trying to remove `div1` and `div2` classes that are on `div`'s:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    
    $("div").removeClass(function (index, className) {
      return (className.match (/div[0-9]/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
    $("p").removeClass("intro");
  });
});
```

```css
.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

.intro {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">div 1</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
<div class="div3">div 3</div>
<div class="div4">div 4</div>
<p class="intro">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="intro">This is another paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Your code and fiddle do not match, am I missing something?